# Loading SVG (XML) with YUI3

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, io, yui

I'm trying to load a SVG file with YUI3. I've read the page about the *IO Utility - YUI Library* and followed the [example given there](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#yui_3_18_1_1_1436790307460_146). I wrote

```
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    YUI().use("io", function(Y) {
        Y.io('test.svg', {
            on: {
                success: function(id, o) {
                    console.log('success: ' + o.status + " ==> " + o.responseText);
                },
                failure: function(id, o) {
                    console.log('failure: ' + o.status + " ==> " + o.statusText);
                }
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

The real strange thing is, that on running the script I get a "failure: 0 ==>", thus `o.status` is 0, which is not a HTTP status code and there is no `o.statusText`, although the `failure` event is triggered.

Here you can download the [two files in a zip file](http://www.flashbrain.org/depot/stackoverflow-yui-io.zip).

What I'am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing the html directly in the browser? In order for Ajax to function the file needs to be on a webserver. If you are using a mac, spin up a single line webserver in the directory you are in like this: 
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Once I had your code running under a webserver it loaded the SVG properly.

Comment: Thank you so much jayla!!!! This is the solution. So far I have only worked with the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) framework. However all jQuery ajax functions work perfectly localy and on a server...